# Audio output device just producing a clicking sound

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a USB audio device (Line6 Pod GX) that works as an audio input as well as audio output device.  I was surprised to see this device worked perfectly out of the box with a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 (just moved over from windows again).

I ran into an issue with Firefox not playing audio and spent some time troubleshooting and installing pavucontrol to try and change the output.  After giving up on Firefox audio and just using another browser I found that my USB audio device no longer worked correctly.  It still appears in the Ubuntu Audio settings, as well as in Pavucontrol.  The issue is when I select this as my output device now I don't get the desired output and instead just get a constant "click click click click" sound coming out of the speaker.

I have reinstalled alsa/pulseaudio, I have tried different USB ports, and I have confirmed the device still works in windows.  After lots of searching with no leads I have come here, hoping someone has had an issue like this.

Other than clearing my user settings for pulse audio and killing / restarting alsa and pulse audio I haven't done anything I could see triggering this issue.

Does anyone have ideas on how to resolve this issue or a lead on where I could start looking for a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea how this happened but if anyone else comes across this thread I fixed the issue.

**Fix:** Opened `alsamixer` and played with the different Input Response channels.  Setting one of them to 0 fixed the problem.

I'm going to do some searching to learn about impulse response, but if anyone reads this that knows about it, feel free to chime in!